# Being $o(x)\mid o(y)$, can we say that $x$ is a recurrence of $y$ (if $x$ is the power of $y$)?

Tags: group-theory, recurrence-relations, order-theory

I've got a non cyclic group called G and x and y two elements from G. And $o(x)\mid o(y)$. Can we say that $x$ is a recurrence of $y$?

---

I think that we can't but I don't really know how to justificate it.

Comment: what is a recurrence?

Comment: I mean, is it true that y^(something)=x ?

Comment: I see. You mean that x is a power of y.

Comment: Can you think of any group which contains two elements of the same order?

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted to say

Comment: Can you think of any noncyclic group which contains two elements of the same order? :)

Comment: mmmm... I have no idea :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107780/discussion-between-maialen-and-alexander-gruber).

Comment: What's the smallest group that you can think of that isn't cyclic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$C_2\times C_2=\{1,x,y,xy|\ x^2=y^2=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1\}$ Then $o(x)|o(y)$ but $y^k\in \{1,y\}$

Comment: And if G is cyclic, how can I prove that beaing o(x)\o(y) is true that I can put x as a power of y? (it's not enough to give an example, I need to prove it)

Comment: If $G$ us cyclic then $\exists x\in G$ s.t every $y\in G$ is of the form $x^k,\ k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't think so :|